# How can i make a 3.3v ouput from 9v battery?

Tags: arduino, current, wifi, ftdi, esp8266

I'm a newbie in embeded system and basic electronics ,Yesterday i purchased a esp8266 wifi module from amazon along with ftdi usb driver i'm also have an Arduino uno, esp8266 require 3.3 v . Arduino and ftdi driver has a 3.3v pin but the tutorial i watched suggest that not connect esp with arduino or ftdi ,so how can i start working with esp from a 9v battery?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to buy a 3.3V voltage regulator. You can find a large amount of different ones. [This](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LD1117V33.pdf) is one example.

The regulator will take in the 9V input (and a ground signal) to produce a 3.3v output referenced with the same ground signal.

Comment: You could also consider a switching type regulator module, these are more energy efficient making your battery last longer. http://www.ebay.nl/itm/Mini-360-DC-DC-Buck-Converter-Step-Down-Module-4-75V-23V-to-1V-17V-d-/231317805938?hash=item35db9d9b72:g:2icAAOSwDN1USMla  Note that you will need a multimeter to measure the output voltage, set it to 3.3 V using the small adjustment wheel on the module.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a good switching regulator is the best option, as long as you study the datasheet properly. 
But other options are whipping up a linear regulator with a NPN transistor and zener diode.
Or if you know that the current draw is going to be reasonably constant you could use just a zener or even a voltage divider (which is horribly inefficient but quick and cheap).

An example of a simple linear voltage regulator you will need to play around with R1 and C1 to suit your situation but heres the gist. Works well in very low power situations, with very little noise.
I should add the model number of the transistor is not important just any common NPN will do (depending on power consumption). This would be good for about 0.25 to 0.5 A current draw.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7zgpz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your zener must be 0.6 volt less than 3.3V. If you use 3.9V zener then your output will be 3.9+0.6=4.5V.

Comment: @soosaisteven No sorry you're wrong, I was correct. But by all means do your own research.

Comment: Yes... I'm sorry, you are right. The emitter is more negative than the base. The zener got to be 3.9 volts.